# problems with NA in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have problems with missing values NA in data.table. When using mean(x) BY=z, I got NA if some of observations in a group with the same value of z has x=NA. How I can treat that?

Comment: This Q is not specific to `data.table` but to `mean` or to how `NA` are handled in `R` in general. Please, have a look at `?mean`.

Answer (score 3):

As you have not provided any example data, its hard to guess what are you trying to do. However, here is a sample example to exclude the `NA` values from calculation. Consider a data table `dt`

```
dt = data.table(mtcars)[1:6][2, mpg := NA][]                   

     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2:   NA   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Where you have `NA` value in second row of first column. If you are interested to calculate the mean of first column, you can use `na.rm`.

```
mean(dt$mpg, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 20.06129
```

Or, when doing by-group calculations:

```
dt[, mean(mpg, na.rm = TRUE), by=cyl]
#    cyl       V1
# 1:   6 20.16667
# 2:   4 22.80000
# 3:   8 18.70000
```